# What external authentication service can I use to secure my Jenkins Continuous Integration environment?

Tags: authentication, jenkins, security

Jenkins CI comes with a number of built-in security options like authentication, SSL...etc ([described here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Securing+Jenkins)).

Because there are always security vulnerabilities that could be discovered with Jenkins CI ([like these](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Security+Advisories)) and upgrading Jenkins CI immediately is sometimes difficult due to plug-in bugs, is there another way to easily secure Jenkins CI with encrypted login authentication without it being on Jenkins itself? (I'm using Jenkins on a Windows OS).

What I would like to have is a completely separate authentication service for all users of Jenkins CI which they have to authenticated against prior to them actually being able to use Jenkins CI. Do any of you know some possible solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

The [standard security setup page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup) describes how to configure different options for authenticating users. For windows it recommends installing the [active directory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin).